# Rewrite rule for everything except a folder

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, zend-framework

I have an application that uses Zend Framework but has a WordPress blog under the public directory (folder is named "blog").

Accessing the blog's homepage is fine, but when I try to access the posts, my htaccess rules have it go through Zend Framework. What do I need to modify in my /public/.htaccess file to have it ignore requests to the /public/blog directory?

Here's the current .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, this should work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/blog/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Andrey, but I'm afraid it still goes through ZF for URLs like /blog/about or /blog/2012/somepost. Accessing /blog though is fine, it gets routed through WordPress.

Comment: Answer is partially correct though. The thing that was messing up was the WordPress .htacess file located under /public/blog. The .htaccess file under /public was routing fine to that directory, but the RewriteRule parameter used by WordPress needed a bit of tweaking to this:

`RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]`

Thanks!